# ionic v1 app custom icon

Tags: javascript, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-fcm, ionic-v1

I have deleted all ionic default icon from resources/android folder and platform /android/res folder and managed to change the app launcher.

[image]

But the icon in split screen still uses the ionic logo(where does this come from??? I already deleted all)
[image]

And..as in the documentation

⚠️ For Android >5.0 status bar icon, you must include transparent solid color icon with name 'fcm_push_icon.png' in the 'res' folder in the same way you add the other application icons. If you do not set this resource, then the SDK will use the default icon for your app which may not meet the standards for Android >5.0.

If somehow it doesn't find fcm_push_icon.png, i should use the app default icon which I already changed as above.
But it doesn't do that[image] too.. I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0):

You need delete icon. png and in resources folder and put your custom icon  and renamed it into icon.png(icon image’s minimum dimensions should be 192×192 px)

Execute the command
 ionic resources --icon

Check the resources /android folder for checking whether your icon is generated....

Then build android

Check your res folder.... Your icon will be generated...

Copy all the folder in res. Paste the copied folder and files in platform android res..

Then you will get the icon..

Answer (score 0):

Go to 
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit

Generate your icon. for this you have to choose image with transparent background. this url give you 5 folder called drawable-xxx. put all 5 folders in your platform/android/res location. if your icon name icon_fcm.png then put following code in your payload

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("to", "user token");

JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
info.put("title", "your app name"); 
info.put("body",  your message); 
info.put("sound", "default"); 
info.put("icon", "icon_fcm"); 
info.put("color", "color code"); 

json.put("notification", w_info);
```

this will work !